# How can I change the resting position of a rig from T-pose to A-pose

Tags: rigging, bmesh

[image: enter link description here]

[image: enter link description here]

The avatar is in a T-Pose and the weighing etc. works, but I want to put it in an A, standing position so that I can more easily create clothing for it. But whenever I reposition the rig, the weights break and nothing wants to work. I wanted to try making a new resting position to see if it works, but I do not understand how to do it. I've read multiple logs and don't understand any of them.

Comment: Please use the builtin image upload feature in the editing toolbar only, your images are not easily visible. Also edit your title to be descriptive of your problem.

Comment: Please use a title for the question that describes your problem clearly.

Comment: I think you need to do two things, reshape the mesh to the new pose as well as make the new pose the rest position of the rig. [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8216/935) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15332/935) should help with the rig. I think go to the new pose and then apply the armature modifier to reshape the mesh, then alter the rest pose of the rig and create a new armature modifier, you won't need to re-parent and weight, just add an armature modifier and select the rig.